# Microsoft Access Left Join Query Giving "Invalid Operation" Error

Tags: microsoft-access, sql

Here's the question: I'm getting an "Invalid Operation" error on a `LEFT JOIN` query and, although I think I can identify the field causing the issue, I can't figure out *why* and what to do to fix it. What am I missing / what do I need to change to get it to work?

---

I'm working with 4 linked tables that go into 2 different select queries (`ex_Step1` and `ex_Step2`) and then those 2 queries go into a 3rd query (`ex_Step3`). When I try to run the third query, I get a "Invalid Operation" error. I don't modify any of the original data except for the following cases:

- `Switch` to translate from a system-generated code into a project name for human readability
- `Sum` to add together two different numbers
- `Trim` to remove trailing spaces from a work order number

Here's an explanation of what the queries are supposed to do:

- We have NCRs (non-conformance records) that might create a WO (work order) to do some repair or rework activity correcting whatever the issue was
- Not every NCR creates a WO and not every WO is created by an NCR
- The NCR table has a field for if a WO is created as well as other information about the NCR
- The WO table has a record of all the hours spent doing the work but not a field for which NCR number created it
- I have to link the NCR data and the WO data based on the WO number
- I want to extract all the hours for each WO that was created by an NCR and connect that to the date that the NCR was closed
- `ex_Step1`extracts data about every WO whose number starts with `N` since every WO created by an NCR gets a number starting with `N`
- `ex_Step2` extracts data about every NCR tied to a work order that starts with `N`
- `ex_Step3` is *supposed* to pull in every record from `ex_Step1` and, if the WO number appears in `ex_Step2`, it should pull in the NCR information like number, date created, and date closed
- In the event that a WO starts with `N` and doesn't have a corresponding entry in the NCR table, I plan to use the `DATE_MC` field in `ex_Step1` but I haven't gotten far enough for that to be an issue yet.

Here are some things I've found out based on the troubleshooting I've done so far and some supporting thoughts:

- The error only occurs when `ex_Step3` uses a `LEFT JOIN` with `ex_Step1` on the left. A regular join is no issue and a join with `ex_Step2` on the left is no issue.
- The `JOIN` is on the fields `ex_Step1.tWO_NBR` and `ex_Step2.tWO_NK`. (The two underlying linked tables had different names for the same data)
- Those two are the two fields with `Trim` applied to them (in `ex_Step1` and `ex_Step2`) because one table had trailing spaces and the other does not so the join only worked with the spaces removed
- If I use a `LEFT JOIN` but don't include any records from the right-hand table (`ex_Step2`), then `ex_Step3` runs without error. I presume this is because it ignores the join as we're only pulling data from the left table.
- I've tried wrapping the `ON` statement in parentheses - as shown in the SQL below - but with no effect

---

Here's the SQL for the queries. I have sanitized the data to remove the project names but I have made no other changes. For `ex_Step1`:

```
SELECT WDS17_ORD.STKRM, Switch([STKRM]="14","Proj1",[STKRM]="16","Proj2",[STKRM]="26","Proj3",[STKRM]="28","Proj4") AS Project, Trim([WO_NBR]) AS tWO_NBR, WDS17_LDD.WO_ACCT, WDS17_ORD.DATE_MC, Sum([WDS17_LDD]![HRS_REG]+[WDS17_LDD]![HRS_OT1]) AS Hours
FROM WDS17_LDD RIGHT JOIN WDS17_ORD ON WDS17_LDD.WO_ACCT = WDS17_ORD.WO_NBR
GROUP BY WDS17_ORD.STKRM, Switch([STKRM]="14","Proj1",[STKRM]="16","Proj2",[STKRM]="26","Proj3",[STKRM]="28","Proj4"), Trim([WO_NBR]), WDS17_LDD.WO_ACCT, WDS17_ORD.DATE_MC
HAVING (((WDS17_ORD.STKRM)="14" Or (WDS17_ORD.STKRM)="16" Or (WDS17_ORD.STKRM)="26" Or (WDS17_ORD.STKRM)="28") AND ((Trim([WO_NBR])) Like "N*") AND ((Sum([WDS17_LDD]![HRS_REG]+[WDS17_LDD]![HRS_OT1]))>0))
ORDER BY Switch([STKRM]="14","Proj1",[STKRM]="16","Proj2",[STKRM]="26","Proj3",[STKRM]="28","Proj4"), WDS17_ORD.DATE_MC DESC , Sum([WDS17_LDD]![HRS_REG]+[WDS17_LDD]![HRS_OT1]) DESC;
```

... and for `ex_Step2`:

```
SELECT Trim([REWORK_WO_NK]) AS tWO_NK, DW_OWNER_NCM_DISP_REWORK_WO_FACT.NCR_NUMBER_NK AS NCR_NUMBER, DW_OWNER_NCM_NCR.DATE_CREATE, DW_OWNER_NCM_NCR.DATE_CLOSE
FROM DW_OWNER_NCM_DISP_REWORK_WO_FACT INNER JOIN DW_OWNER_NCM_NCR ON DW_OWNER_NCM_DISP_REWORK_WO_FACT.NCM_NCR_SK = DW_OWNER_NCM_NCR.NCM_NCR_SK
GROUP BY Trim([REWORK_WO_NK]), DW_OWNER_NCM_DISP_REWORK_WO_FACT.NCR_NUMBER_NK, DW_OWNER_NCM_NCR.DATE_CREATE, DW_OWNER_NCM_NCR.DATE_CLOSE
HAVING (((Trim([REWORK_WO_NK])) Like "N*"))
ORDER BY DW_OWNER_NCM_NCR.DATE_CREATE, DW_OWNER_NCM_NCR.DATE_CLOSE;
```

... and for `ex_Step3`:

```
SELECT ex_Step1.STKRM, ex_Step1.Project, ex_Step1.tWO_NBR, ex_Step1.WO_ACCT, ex_Step1.DATE_MC, ex_Step1.Hours, ex_Step2.NCR_NUMBER, ex_Step2.DATE_CREATE, ex_Step2.DATE_CLOSE
FROM ex_Step1 LEFT JOIN ex_Step2 ON (ex_Step1.tWO_NBR = ex_Step2.tWO_NK);
```

Comment: Here's a thought.  Create a query that joins only the NBR number to the WO number.  If you use a full outer join, you can get all the data from both tables (both a left and right join) into a query result table.  From there, link all three tables and pull out the information you need.

Comment: I've never used a full outer join - my SQL knowledge is limited to Access - but I looked up how to fake it. A few different attempts yielded the same error. However, you inspired me to look at workarounds. For my application, it's OK to have the first 2 queries be Make Tables and the 3rd to just join those two. That worked a charm. - - - I'd like to close this question and give you some credit for inspiration. Is deletion the only route I have? I don't see how to self-answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answer is being posted to avoid leaving the question open and unanswered so that it may serve as reference for future generations.

---

I attempted a full outer join as was suggested in the comments but was unable to get it working. It's not natively implemented in Access 2010 and the workarounds I found were unsuccessful. My eventual solution was to setup my base queries as Make Table queries and use the tables as the source for my third query. For my implementation, that was sufficient.

Comment: That idea helped solve my problem as well.